# create a dynamic validation in JavaScript for a structure "if"

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a dynamic validation in JavaScript for a structure "if" for example:

```
    var var1=1;
    var comparator="!==";
    var var2=1;
    if(var1+comparator+var2){
        alert("Yes, its false");
    }else{
        alert("Yes, its true");
    }
```

The Three variables could change as the user desires. I've discovered that the sentence always is validated "true", because the structure "if" validate that the String exist.

What I want is, that the user changes any of this three variable and the function returns the result. Obviously, the comparison operator is controlled by other function that restrict the options for the operators to: "===", "!==" ...

Thanks and regards

Comment: See my answer below - how to do this properly depends a lot on where `var1`, `var2`, and `comparator` come from. Edit your question to explain your application so that we can give you better advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to do this:

```
eval(var1+comparator+var2)
```

Is this a good idea however depends on what exactly you're doing. Where do `var1`,`var1`, and `comparator` come from? If the user is typing them in themselves that is not a problem. Even if they are loaded from the server it's not a huge problem.

HOWEVER, if this is something that a user can submit to the server, and then have it displayed in ANOTHER user's browser that's a **hugely** bad idea as they can submit arbitrary javascript and have it execute in other users' browsers. This is called a Cross Site Scripting (XSS) injection.

Comment: Eval doesn't work with strings! proof -->http://jsfiddle.net/MarkkNijboer/PDw97/
The thing is that the string get out of the quotations. So it works with numbers as a string because it becomes an integer. A string cannot stay a string, the way you present your answer.

Comment: @MarkNijboer yes, but that's not *really* a string, that's actually a reference to a global variable named "test". If the OP wanted that as a string they would have to of course quote it.

Comment: try replacing the string with an integer and it works. Even a string that only has a number will work but a string with letters won't.

Comment: As I said, this is because what you're passing in is not really a string any more than passing a "1" into an eval is a string (it is not). In the context of an eval it is a reference to a variable named `test` in the current context. A quoted `"'test'"` string would work just fine

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. And thanks very much for the extra advices (@GeorgeMauer / @MarkNijboer). As you say, I gonna use this logic to execute a set of validations, stored in a Array like:

Comment: arrIDH[["id",'!=',"''"],["val",'==',"'1'"]]; and in a function get this array, to validate different tuples.

Comment: What? What do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something along these lines?

```
var comparator = '===';

var comparators = {
  '===': function(a, b) {
  return a === b;
  }
};

if (comparators[comparator](var1, var2)) {
  alert("Yes, its false");
}else{
  alert("Yes, its true");
}
```

Comment: No need to do call `comparators[comparator](var1, var2)` should work just fine

Comment: I've fixed it in the anwser.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this - JavaScript will just treat them all as strings and concatenate them together; which will always return true.

You would need dedicated statements like `if` or `switch` and then use the real operators to make your comparisons.

Example:

```
var var1=1;
var comparator="!==";
//var comparator = "=="; // presumes user input, commented out in this example
var var2=1;

switch (comparator) 
{
    case "!==": 
        alert(var1 !== var2);
        break;
    case "==":
        alert(var1 == var2);
        break;
}
```

Comment: Your's is probably more pragmatic though :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well what you want, you can use "Function" or "eval"

```
var result = eval(var1+comparator+var2);
```

or

```
var result = new Function("return " + var1+comparator+var2)();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an approach of mine: **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/vakasori/2/edit?js,console)**

```
function compare(a, op, b){

  var operators = {
    ">" :  a>b  ? "Great!" : "Wrong",
    "<" :  a<b  ? "Great!" : "Wrong",
    "!=":  a!=b ? "Great. Not equal!" : "Wrong"
  };
  return operators[op];

}

compare(10, ">", 20)  // Wrong
```

Comment: Any reason you use `_` as a variable name here? Usually I see it in reference either to the underscore library or (for people with a functional languages background) to parameters you don't use in the function body.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer I've used `_` in the means of `a` `symbol` `b`. and the chance to make a nice box `[_]` was not an opportunity to miss